# How can I animate elements moving after hiding other elements affecting their positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make my title and welcome footer of my login screen slowly ease together, rather than snapping together when I fade out the input form, here is a jsfiddle I whipped up to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/91ac4g0f/5/

Like I said, instead of the text snapping together I want it to ease together once the input form is out of the way.

Code from fiddle:

html

```
<div class="flexer">
  <h3 class="transition">
    Site Name
  </h3>
  <div class="seperator"></div>
  <div id="hide">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password Confirmation"><br>
  </div>
  <h1 class="transition">
    Welcome
  </h1>
</div>
```

css

```
.hideani {
  animation: fadeout 2s;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.flexer {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #37474F;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h3, h1 {
  margin: 5px;
}

.seperator {
  width: 30%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 200;
}


/* attempt from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364938/how-to-animate-elements-move-with-css3-transitions-after-hiding-some-element */
// Didn't seem to work
.transition {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}

input {
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}
```

js

```
setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("hide").className = "hideani";
}, 2000)

setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("hide").className += " hide";
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code and came up with this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91ac4g0f/7/)

```
var siteName = document.getElementById("h3");
  var welcome = document.getElementById("h1");

 setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("hide").className = "hideani";
}, 2000)

setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("hide").className += " hide";
    siteName.style.top = "113px"
  welcome.style.top = "147px"
}, 4000);
```

I repositioned your `h1,h3` absolutely so i can control it with the js using its `top`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the title and welcome footer of the login screen slowly ease together by changing the opacity of the the input to zero `opacity: 0.0;` for two seconds before doing `display: none;` in order to allow for the movement to take place.

Check out the fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/Lwsbh8fp/1/

and here are the codes:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("hide").className = "hideani";
}, 2000)

setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("a").className += " movea";
}, 4000);

setTimeout(() => {
 document.getElementById("b").className += " moveb";
}, 4000);

setTimeout(() => {
 document.getElementById("c").className += " movec";
}, 4000);

setTimeout(() => {
 document.getElementById("hide").className += " hide";
}, 4000);

setTimeout(() => {
 document.getElementById("hide").className += " none";
}, 6000);
```

```css
.hideani {
  animation: fadeout 2s;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

.movea {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: examplea;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: examplea;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes examplea {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    100%  {left:0px; top:-56px;}
}

@keyframes examplea {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    100%  {left:0px; top:-56px;}
}

.moveb {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: exampleb;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: exampleb;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes exampleb {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    100%  {left:0px; top:56px;}
}

@keyframes exampleb {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    100%  {left:0px; top:56px;}
}

.movec {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: examplec;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-name: examplec;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes examplec {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    100%  {left:0px; top:56px;}
}

@keyframes examplec {
    0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}
    100%  {left:0px; top:56px;}
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.flexer {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #37474F;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h3, h1 {
  margin: 5px;
}

.seperator {
  width: 30%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 200;
}


/* attempt from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364938/how-to-animate-        elements-move-with-css3-transitions-after-hiding-some-element */
// Didn't seem to work
.transition {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}

input {
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexer">
  <h3 id="b" class="transition">
    Site Name
  </h3>
  <div id="c" class="seperator"></div>
  <div id="hide">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password Confirmation"><br>
  </div>
  <h1 id="a" class="transition">
    Welcome
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All are so good.But the without mention `height` Its wont give ah effect.
Simply add **height of the `hide` box**  its show the effect. **[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91ac4g0f/8/)***

Reduce the height of the  `hide` box apply the `forwards` effect of animation its with hide with end of the animation.No need to use `display:none` with hide class

```
#hide {
  height:120px;
  overflow:hidden;
 transition:all 1s ease;
}
```

```js
setTimeout(() => {
 
  document.getElementById("hide").className = "hideani";
  document.getElementById("hide").style.height = "1px";
}, 2000)
```

```css
.hideani {
  
  animation: fadeout 0.5s forwards;
}

#hide {
  height:120px;
  overflow:hidden;
 transition:all 1s ease;
}

.flexer {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #37474F;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h3, h1 {
  margin: 5px;
}

.seperator {
  width: 30%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 200;
}


/* attempt from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364938/how-to-animate-elements-move-with-css3-transitions-after-hiding-some-element */
// Didn't seem to work
.transition {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}

input {
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexer">
  <h3 class="transition">
    Site Name
  </h3>
  <div class="seperator"></div>
  <div id="hide">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password Confirmation"><br>
  </div>
  <h1 class="transition">
    Welcome
  </h1>
</div>
```